# Liferay: GA4 on an empty MySQL 5.7 results in a fatal exception

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to install Liferay GA4 and a Master build for development purposes. However I keep falling into a fatal exception with MySQL 5.7.

As described at: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-73410

> In an empty database, MySQL 5.7, when the servers is brought up the follow exception is raised. (seem on both drivers com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver)
>
> liferay          | 21:45:35,927 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][MainServlet:275] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'XXXXX.EVENTS' doesn't exist
>
> liferay          | com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'XXXXX.EVENTS' doesn't exist

I was wondering if this is something I can get around by some procedure done directly into the database...Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my way out this issue with new JDBC defaults.

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://${database.host}/${database.schema}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false&useSSL=false&nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true&&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true
```

From: https://www.e-systems.tech/web/guest/blog/-/blogs/liferay-with-mysql-5-7-driver-changes

Comment: As you also link the issue in Liferay's issue tracker, it would be nice to post this as workaround/fix there as well.